# Empty notification list

Tags: bug, android-app, notifications

> [image]

Happens after opening the app through the notification drawer.

Comment: About the 10th report of same bug...

Comment: @ShadowWizard: How many does it require for a bug to get fixed? ;)

Comment: lol, wish it was that simple! :D