# Error after posting new question

Tags: bug, android-app

After posting [Empty notification list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266660/empty-notification-list), I received this error:

[image]

Comment: Looks very similar to [my problem on iOS](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226213/245360).

Comment: @PatrickHofman yeah, looks like API issue, that sometimes isn't "fast" enough.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Just put a `while(++i<999999){}` in there. It'll be fine.

Comment: (already voted to close on a wrong one by mistake, but you can self-close all by yourself)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I kinda feel like *I* reported this one in the past already as well…